# Phaser CE switch state

Tags: ecmascript-6, phaser-framework

```
import {InitState} from './states/InitState';
import {SelectState} from './states/SelectState';

someFunction()
{

this._game = new Phaser.Game(800,400,Phaser.AUTO);

this._game.state.add('INIT_STATE',InitState);
this._game.state.add('SELECT_STATE',SelectState);
this._game.state.start('INIT_STATE');
}
```

And my phaser state class looks like this:

```
export class InitState extends Phaser.State
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        console.log("[InitState] constructor");
    }
    preload()
    {
        console.log("[InitState] preload");
    }
    create()
    {
       console.log("[InitState] create");
      this.game.state.start('SELECT_STATE');
    }
}
```

So now when I start my first state (“INIT_STATE'”) everything works fine, but when I try to switch to another state “SELECT_STATE” nothing happens.

If someone see something wrong please tell me.

When I debug.

First state have params:{ game: P…r.Game, key: "SELECT_STATE"} etc.
Second state haven’t any params:{ game: null, key: "", add: null, make: null, camera: null}
Why this happened?

I try to run Phaser 2.8.0 with es6 babel .

Regards

Comment: Maybe there is an error or typo in the SelectState object, causing it not to be instantiated? Are there any other error messages in the JavaScript console before the INI_STATE starts?

Comment: No I use static const so the names are the same. No errors before or after. Just phaser don't switch states.